# What does .container.\31 25\25 mean in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the code below, I am wondering what the `\` backslash might mean? I have not encounter the backslash character in the lessons I've been taking. This piece of code is used to identify browser sizes, I believe.

```css
.container.\31 25\25 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;  /* max-width: (containers * 1.25) */
  min-width: 1200px;  /* min-width: (containers) */
}
.container.\37 5\25 { /* 75% */
  width: 900px;       /* width: (containers * 0.75) */
}
.container.\35 0\25 { /* 50% */
  width: 600px;       /* width: (containers * 0.50) */
}
.container.\32 5\25 { /* 25% */
  width: 300px;       /* width: (containers * 0.25) */
}
```

Comment: The code is poorly written. You should not use it unless forced to. As a CSS novice, you should not even read it unless forced to. The mess is caused by the use of class names like `125%`, which are (formally valid but) bad in more than one way.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela What are the ways in which they are bad?

Comment: @torazaburo, they reflect an intended rendering rather than structural or semantic role (and become misleading if the rendering is changed); and they force you to use clumsy escape mechanisms in CSS, as shown in the question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters),

> Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646
>   character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the
>   identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F". [...]
>
> In CSS 2.1, a backslash (\) character can
>   indicate one of three types of character escape. Inside a CSS comment,
>   a backslash stands for itself, and if a backslash is immediately
>   followed by the end of the style sheet, it also stands for itself
>   (i.e., a DELIM token).
>
> First, inside a string, a backslash followed by a newline is ignored
>   (i.e., the string is deemed not to contain either the backslash or the
>   newline). Outside a string, a backslash followed by a newline stands
>   for itself (i.e., a DELIM followed by a newline).
>
> Second, it cancels the meaning of special CSS characters. Any
>   character (except a hexadecimal digit, linefeed, carriage return, or
>   form feed) can be escaped with a backslash to remove its special
>   meaning. For example, "\"" is a string consisting of one double quote.
>   Style sheet preprocessors must not remove these backslashes from a
>   style sheet since that would change the style sheet's meaning.
>
> Third, backslash escapes allow authors to refer to characters they
>   cannot easily put in a document. In this case, the backslash is
>   followed by at most six hexadecimal digits (0..9A..F), which stand for
>   the ISO 10646 ([ISO10646]) character with that number, which must not
>   be zero. (It is undefined in CSS 2.1 what happens if a style sheet
>   does contain a character with Unicode codepoint zero.) If a character
>   in the range [0-9a-fA-F] follows the hexadecimal number, the end of
>   the number needs to be made clear. There are two ways to do that:
>
> 1. with a space (or other white space character): "\26 B" ("&B"). In this case, user agents should treat a "CR/LF" pair (U+000D/U+000A) as
>      a single white space character.
> 2. by providing exactly 6 hexadecimal digits: "\000026B" ("&B")
>
> In fact, these two methods may be combined. Only one white space
>   character is ignored after a hexadecimal escape. Note that this means
>   that a "real" space after the escape sequence must be doubled.
>
> If the number is outside the range allowed by Unicode (e.g., "\110000"
>   is above the maximum 10FFFF allowed in current Unicode), the UA may
>   replace the escape with the "replacement character" (U+FFFD). If the
>   character is to be displayed, the UA should show a visible symbol,
>   such as a "missing character" glyph (cf. 15.2, point 5).

Therefore, the following are equivalent:

```css
.container.\31 25\25   <-->   .container[class ~= "125%"]
.container.\37 5\25    <-->   .container[class ~= "75%"]
.container.\35 0\25    <-->   .container[class ~= "50%"]
.container.\32 5\25    <-->   .container[class ~= "25%"]
```

Note that escaping is important, otherwise they wouldn't be valid identifiers (emphasis mine):

> In CSS, *identifiers* (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html)) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they **cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit.

Therefore, the following are invalid:

```css
.container.125%
.container.75%
.container.50%
.container.25%
```

Maybe it may be clearer with this fiddle:

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.container.\31 25\25 { /* 125% */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;  /* (containers * 1.25) */
  min-width: 1200px;  /* (containers * 1.00) */
}
.container.\37 5\25 { /* 75% */
  width: 900px;       /* (containers * 0.75) */
}
.container.\35 0\25 { /* 50% */
  width: 600px;       /* (containers * 0.50) */
}
.container.\32 5\25 { /* 25% */
  width: 300px;       /* (containers * 0.25) */
}
```

```html
<div class="container 125%">125%</div>
<div class="container 75%">75%</div>
<div class="container 50%">50%</div>
<div class="container 25%">25%</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was very helpful, but not very easy to understand. It will take some time. Anyhow, what is this piece of code trying to perform with the backslash character? This code piece is from a part of a skel reset css sheet that states what and how to display the contents on different viewports and container sizes.

Comment: @ElizabethChau268 If you don't escape, it won't be a valid identifier. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit. It really helped me out a lot. I could see the pattern and the resemblance with the class selectors / identifiers. I have better understood css a bit more. I didn't know that identifiers could only contain the [a-zA-Z0-9] characters, this is important to know. Also, looking at the examples and fiddle you gave me, it benefited me a lot on understanding the formatting. I still haven't got the ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher part, but I'll try to figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Oriol, just one quick question. Where does the 3 in the 31, 37, 35 and 32 ... come in? Why 3? and why 25? Is it mandatory or just a random number?

Comment: @ElizabebethChau268 Because `31` is the hexadecimal code of `1`, `32` is the code of `2`, and so on. You can convert an hex code to char with `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex,16))`, and convert char to code with `char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)`.