# Use of backslash in CSS selector

Tags: css

I found somewhere that I can use backslash in CSS id# as an exception on some pages that have two id names in same selector. And it works, but I can't find any reference and what version of CSS can use it. Any explanation?

CSS:

```
#content\ shopWide .someclass {
  width: 37px;
  background: khaki;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content shopWide"><div class="someclass">blah</div>
```

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882839/what-does-container-31-25-25-mean-in-css

Comment: It's not "two ID names", it's one ID containing space character. Escaping this character with backslash makes it work in the CSS selector.