# What is the meaning of this unconventional CSS code?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Helping a client update their Shopify theme. The previous designer used an unconventional method for the base grid. I need help translating the code.

Read an old article about this subject, but I still did not understand.

```
$phone:            "screen and (max-width: 640px)";
$tablet:           "screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1007px)";
$tablet-and-up:    "screen and (min-width: 641px)";
$pocket:           "screen and (max-width: 1007px)";
$lap:              "screen and (min-width: 1008px) and (max-width: 1239px)";
$lap-and-up:       "screen and (min-width: 1008px)";
$desk:             "screen and (min-width: 1240px)";
$widescreen:       "screen and (min-width: 1500px)";

.\31\/2, .\32\/4, .\36\/12 {
  width: 50%;
}

.\31\/3, .\34\/12 {
  width: 33.33333%;
}

.\32\/3, .\38\/12 {
  width: 66.66667%;
}

.\31\/4, .\33\/12 {
  width: 25%;
}

.\33\/4, .\39\/12 {
  width: 75%;
}

.\31\/12 {
  width: 8.33333%;
}

.\32\/12 {
  width: 16.66667%;
}

.\35\/12 {
  width: 41.66667%;
}

.\37\/12 {
  width: 58.33333%;
}

.\31\30\/12 {
  width: 83.33333%;
}

.\31\31\/12 {
  width: 91.66667%;
}

@media #{$phone} {
  .hidden-phone {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .\31\/2--phone, .\32\/4--phone, .\36\/12--phone {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .\31\/3--phone, .\34\/12--phone {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/3--phone, .\38\/12--phone {
    width: 66.66667%;
  }

  .\31\/4--phone, .\33\/12--phone {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .\33\/4--phone, .\39\/12--phone {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .\31\/12--phone {
    width: 8.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/12--phone {
    width: 16.66667%;
  }

  .\35\/12--phone {
    width: 41.66667%;
  }

  .\37\/12--phone {
    width: 58.33333%;
  }

  .\31\30\/12--phone {
    width: 83.33333%;
  }

  .\31\31\/12--phone {
    width: 91.66667%;
  }
}

@media #{$tablet} {
  .hidden-tablet {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .\31\/2--tablet, .\32\/4--tablet, .\36\/12--tablet {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .\31\/3--tablet, .\34\/12--tablet {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/3--tablet, .\38\/12--tablet {
    width: 66.66667%;
  }

  .\31\/4--tablet, .\33\/12--tablet {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .\33\/4--tablet, .\39\/12--tablet {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .\31\/12--tablet {
    width: 8.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/12--tablet {
    width: 16.66667%;
  }

  .\35\/12--tablet {
    width: 41.66667%;
  }

  .\37\/12--tablet {
    width: 58.33333%;
  }

  .\31\30\/12--tablet {
    width: 83.33333%;
  }

  .\31\31\/12--tablet {
    width: 91.66667%;
  }
}

@media #{$tablet-and-up} {
  .hidden-tablet-and-up {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .\31\/2--tablet-and-up, .\32\/4--tablet-and-up, .\36\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .\31\/3--tablet-and-up, .\34\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/3--tablet-and-up, .\38\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 66.66667%;
  }

  .\31\/4--tablet-and-up, .\33\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .\33\/4--tablet-and-up, .\39\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .\31\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 8.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 16.66667%;
  }

  .\35\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 41.66667%;
  }

  .\37\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 58.33333%;
  }

  .\31\30\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 83.33333%;
  }

  .\31\31\/12--tablet-and-up {
    width: 91.66667%;
  }
}

@media #{$pocket} {
  .hidden-pocket {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .\31\/2--pocket, .\32\/4--pocket, .\36\/12--pocket {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .\31\/3--pocket, .\34\/12--pocket {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/3--pocket, .\38\/12--pocket {
    width: 66.66667%;
  }

  .\31\/4--pocket, .\33\/12--pocket {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .\33\/4--pocket, .\39\/12--pocket {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .\31\/12--pocket {
    width: 8.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/12--pocket {
    width: 16.66667%;
  }

  .\35\/12--pocket {
    width: 41.66667%;
  }

  .\37\/12--pocket {
    width: 58.33333%;
  }

  .\31\30\/12--pocket {
    width: 83.33333%;
  }

  .\31\31\/12--pocket {
    width: 91.66667%;
  }
}

@media #{$lap} {
  .hidden-lap {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .\31\/2--lap, .\32\/4--lap, .\36\/12--lap {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .\31\/3--lap, .\34\/12--lap {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/3--lap, .\38\/12--lap {
    width: 66.66667%;
  }

  .\31\/4--lap, .\33\/12--lap {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .\33\/4--lap, .\39\/12--lap {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .\31\/12--lap {
    width: 8.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/12--lap {
    width: 16.66667%;
  }

  .\35\/12--lap {
    width: 41.66667%;
  }

  .\37\/12--lap {
    width: 58.33333%;
  }

  .\31\30\/12--lap {
    width: 83.33333%;
  }

  .\31\31\/12--lap {
    width: 91.66667%;
  }
}

@media #{$lap-and-up} {
  .hidden-lap-and-up {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .\31\/2--lap-and-up, .\32\/4--lap-and-up, .\36\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .\31\/3--lap-and-up, .\34\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/3--lap-and-up, .\38\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 66.66667%;
  }

  .\31\/4--lap-and-up, .\33\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .\33\/4--lap-and-up, .\39\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .\31\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 8.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 16.66667%;
  }

  .\35\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 41.66667%;
  }

  .\37\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 58.33333%;
  }

  .\31\30\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 83.33333%;
  }

  .\31\31\/12--lap-and-up {
    width: 91.66667%;
  }
}

@media #{$desk} {
  .hidden-desk {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .\31\/2--desk, .\32\/4--desk, .\36\/12--desk {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .\31\/3--desk, .\34\/12--desk {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/3--desk, .\38\/12--desk {
    width: 66.66667%;
  }

  .\31\/4--desk, .\33\/12--desk {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .\33\/4--desk, .\39\/12--desk {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .\31\/12--desk {
    width: 8.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/12--desk {
    width: 16.66667%;
  }

  .\35\/12--desk {
    width: 41.66667%;
  }

  .\37\/12--desk {
    width: 58.33333%;
  }

  .\31\30\/12--desk {
    width: 83.33333%;
  }

  .\31\31\/12--desk {
    width: 91.66667%;
  }
}
/* Create each media query */
@media #{$widescreen} {
  .hidden-widescreen {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .\31\/2--widescreen, .\32\/4--widescreen, .\36\/12--widescreen {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .\31\/3--widescreen, .\34\/12--widescreen {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/3--widescreen, .\38\/12--widescreen {
    width: 66.66667%;
  }

  .\31\/4--widescreen, .\33\/12--widescreen {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .\33\/4--widescreen, .\39\/12--widescreen {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .\31\/12--widescreen {
    width: 8.33333%;
  }

  .\32\/12--widescreen {
    width: 16.66667%;
  }

  .\35\/12--widescreen {
    width: 41.66667%;
  }

  .\37\/12--widescreen {
    width: 58.33333%;
  }

  .\31\30\/12--widescreen {
    width: 83.33333%;
  }

  .\31\31\/12--widescreen {
    width: 91.66667%;
  }
}
```

Hoping to understand the patterns for "\31" "\32" "\36" "\37", and hopefully a translation the first 12-grid declarations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does .container.\31 25\25 mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882839/what-does-container-31-25-25-mean-in-css)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Doesn't explain the meaning of the code values or the forward slash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS identifiers, such as classes and IDs, cannot begin with a digit (0 - 9).

*From the spec:*

> [4.1.3 Characters and
>   case](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#characters)
>
> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-z, A-Z, 0-9] and ISO
>   10646 characters U+0080 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the
>   underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a
>   hyphen followed by a digit.

However, the same section also says this:

> Backslash escapes are always considered to be part of an identifier or a string.

This means that, while you cannot start an identifier with a digit, you can use backslash escape code (`\foo`) that will convert to a digit. Note that this rule applies in CSS, but not HTML, where [almost any character combination is an acceptable value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/3597276).

So that's what you're seeing in your code. Numerical HTML class values that must be escaped to work in CSS. Here are some examples:

- `\31` is the [Unicode Code Point](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) for the digit one.
- `\32` is the Unicode Code Point for the digit two.
- `\33` is the Unicode Code Point for the digit three.

Another purpose of the backslash escape in CSS is to cancel the meaning of special characters.

The [forward slash (`/`) has special meaning in CSS](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes). It must, therefore, be escaped for proper use.

So let's now decipher the class names in your code:

```
.\31\/2, .\32\/4, .\36\/12 { width: 50%; }
```

The first escape (`\31`) is Unicode for "1".

The second escape (`\/2`) cancels the special meaning of the forward slash.

So the HTML looks like this:

```
class = "1/2"
class = "2/4"
class = "6/12"
```

Here are a few more from your list:

```
.\31\/3, .\34\/12 { width: 33.33333%; } /* HTML class values = 1/3, 4/12 */
.\32\/3, .\38\/12 { width: 66.66667%; } /* HTML class values = 2/3, 8/12 */
.\31\/12          { width: 8.33333%;  } /* HTML class value  = 1/12      */
.\35\/12          { width: 41.66667%; } /* HTML class value  = 5/12      */
.\31\30\/12       { width: 83.33333%; } /* HTML class value  = 10/12     */
.\31\31\/12       { width: 91.66667%; } /* HTML class value  = 11/12     */
```

Comment: Though it appears this hasn't changed (though I did think so initially), it's probably best to cite the level 3 spec, not CSS2.2.

Comment: If you can find it (assuming it exists) please let me know. I looked briefly and didn't see anything. Thanks. @jhpratt

Comment: Looks like the railway diagrams [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#typedef-ident-token) suffice. `<ident-token>`, specically.

Comment: Yes, I saw those. But the text from the older specs is valid and easier to understand, which is why I used that instead. @jhpratt

Comment: Thank you for your help - this is a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

from what I can gather with what I found online it's mostly escaping going on for some odd naming convention that from what I've read is probably not a great idea to begin with.

```
.\31\/2, .\32\/4, .\36\/12 { /* this */
.1/2, .2/4, .6/12 { /* translates to this */
  width: 50%;
}

.\31\/3, .\34\/12 { /* this */
.1/3, .4/12 { /* translates to this */
  width: 33.33333%;
}
```

I don't know if you've seen this article but the accepted answer breaks it down pretty well. after the `\3` is like the start. then the `\/` is escaping the slash.

[What does .container.\31 25\25 mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882839/what-does-container-31-25-25-mean-in-css)

Comment: Thank you for this ... totally understandable now. Not sure I like this method.

Comment: No worries glad I could help. Mind voting it the correct answer since it helped you out.