# Css selector throwing errors when getting it from the dom

Tags: javascript, dom

div#PageContainer > div.container-AD > div:nth-child(4) > div > div.collection__content > div.collection__products.td-collection__products.collection__products--three.td-sticky-filter__container > div.collection__productsBottom.js-collection__productsBottom > div.collection__productsBottomWrapper > div.product.\31 > div > div

i got this selector from google chrome when i right clicked on the element,selected copy and copied the selector from this website [https://bruntworkwear.com/collections/boots[1](https://bruntworkwear.com/collections/boots) which is the first item on the page. but then when i use document.querySelector() i get an error saying it's not a valid selector. How do i get around this?

```
document.querySelector('div#PageContainer > div.container-AD > div:nth-child(4) > div > div.collection__content > div.collection__products.td-collection__products.collection__products--three.td-sticky-filter__container > div.collection__productsBottom.js-collection__productsBottom > div.collection__productsBottomWrapper > div.product.\31 > div > div')
```

VM24989:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'div#PageContainer > div.container-AD > div:nth-child(4) > div > div.collection__content > div.collection__products.td-collection__products.collection__products--three.td-sticky-filter__container > div.collection__productsBottom.js-collection__productsBottom > div.collection__productsBottomWrapper > div.product.\31 > div > div' is not a valid selector.
at :1:10

[image]

Comment: Typo?  What is `div.product.\31` expected to do?

Comment: Open your browser debugger and try calling `document.querySelect(X)` with each (">" deliminated here) part of your selector.

Comment: this is what google generated for me. the element has a class="product 1" go it tries to create it like product.\31 where \3 is an escape character. you can read more here 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882839/what-does-container-31-25-25-mean-in-css/27882887#27882887

Comment: Seen as your using in a `string`,  so don't forget about string escaping too..  eg. 
 `div.product.\\31`

Comment: Why not just use `.product > div > div`? It will still get the first product that matches.

Comment: there are several products with that format so it might select the wrong one. they are separated by product number

Comment: @Keith your solution worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`\31` is a CSS escape for the character `1`

But Javascript strings also have escaping too, so if you just do `\31` in your string you will lose this, this is because `\31` will be seen as Octal char, IOW: Hex value 19, and is of course not the same.

The solution is in your Javascript string, just remember to escape the escape,.. `\31` -> `\\31`..

So your full string should be ->
`document.querySelector('div#PageContainer > div.container-AD > div:nth-child(4) > div > div.collection__content > div.collection__products.td-collection__products.collection__products--three.td-sticky-filter__container > div.collection__productsBottom.js-collection__productsBottom > div.collection__productsBottomWrapper > div.product.\\31 > div > div')`