I don't anderstand the meaning of "\" in a css code
I am a new user of css and I have an interrogation on a css code.
I found in a css file :
.container.\31 25\25 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 75em;
    min-width: 60em;
}

What does mean the \ ?
I dont find response in Google
Thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882839/what-does-container-31-25-25-mean-in-css

In CSS, the backslash character is used to escape characters that would otherwise have a special meaning or to represent characters that aren't normally allowed in identifiers.
In your CSS snippet, the \31 25\25 part represents an escaped string.
Specifically:

\31 is the escaped representation of the character 1 (in hexadecimal, 31 is the Unicode code point for 1).
\25 is the hexadecimal code point for the character % (percent sign), but here it's just being used as a literal character in the selector.

So, \31 25\25 translates to 1 % %.
The selector .container.\31 25\25 targets an element with the class container and the additional class 1 % %.
